# Can't load/retrieve cookie, cookie not found

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-10

I've been struggling with cookies in Laravel, and now I've tested twice (on top of my real project) with a freshly made project both times, and the problem persists. `$request->cookie('jwt')` can't find a cookie (in DashboardController.php), and the cookie is confirmed to be set, as it can be printed in browser console. I'm still relatively new to Laravel, but I've tried everything I can come to think of, and of course also Google and ChatGPT. It should be a breeze to set a cookie and retrieve it, done it many times in NodeJS...

I've uploaded the test project: [LINK](https://github.com/casey977/cookie_test)

Laravel 10.46.0
PHP 8.2.7 (^8.1 in Laravel)
Debian 12.5

Controller that sets the cookie (LoginController.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LoginController extends Controller {
    public function login(Request $request) {
        try {
            // Validate input...
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|email|max:100',
                'password' => 'required|string|max:100'
            ]);

            // Check email...
            $client = DB::table('table')->where('email', $validatedData['email'])->first();
            if (is_null($client)) {
                Log::error('Wrong email!');
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Email not found!'], 401);
            }

            // Check password...
            $passwordState = Hash::check($validatedData['password'], $client->password);
            if ($passwordState) {
                $responseData = [
                    'status' => 'OK',
                    'message' => 'Login successful, JWT generated',
                ];
                $response = response()->json($responseData, 200);
                setcookie('jwt', 'qwerty@qwerty.com', 9001);
                return $response;
            } else {
                Log::error('Wrong password');
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Wrong password!'], 401);
            }
        } catch (ValidationException $error) {
            Log::error('Error validating login details!');
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Login details has wrong format!'], 501);
        } catch (Exception $error) {
            Log::error('Unknown error logging in!');
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error logging in!'], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller that is supposed to get the cookie (DashboardController.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use App\Models\Users;

class DashboardController extends Controller {
    public function dashboard(Request $request) {
        $token = $request->cookie('jwt');
        Log::debug($token); // Prints blank/nothing
        if ($request->hasCookie('jwt')) {
            Log::debug('Has cookie!');
            $token = $request->cookie('jwt');
            Log::debug($token); // Is never reached, because the if-condition above is never resolved to true
            // Use data here...
            return view('dashboard');
        } else {
            Log::error('No cookie!'); // Is always printed
        }
    }
}
```

**What I expect:**
I expect `$request->cookie('jwt');` to actually get the cookie, and `$request->hasCookie('jwt')` to return true (or truthy value at least).

**What I actually get:**
`Log::debug($token);` prints blank/nothing in laravel.log and `Log::error('No cookie!');` is always executed.

**Further tests:**
Doing `Cookie::make('jwt', 'qwerty@qwerty.com', 60);` results in same behavior.
Doing `$cookieValue = Cookie::get('jwt'); Log::debug($cookieValue);` results in the same erroneous behavior also.
Doing `$cookie = Cookie::make('jwt', 'qwerty@qwerty.com', 9001); return $response->withCookie($cookie);` makes no difference either.
Changing the cookie names makes no difference either.
Using other browsers make no difference either.

Comment: What are the URLs you are using to access the login and the dashboard routes? You did not specify what path the cookie is supposed to be valid for when setting it, so it will only be valid below the current URL path.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The docs and Google doesn't say anything about specifying path? For example, `$cookie = cookie('user_name', 'John Doe', 60);`, shouldn't that do the trick? How do I set the path(s) for the cookie?

Comment: https://arjunamrutiya.medium.com/mastering-cookies-in-laravel-440bef76fddb, "Step 7: Cookie Options" - now I can't see it saying there, what path is used by default, but if this behaves similar to PHP's native `setcookie`, then the current URL path will be used, if not specified otherwise.

Comment: ChatGPT says that all paths are accepted by default in Laravel...